# Swagger is not enabled after putting @EnableConfigServer annotation in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I an try to enable Swagger 2.0 in the spring cloud config application (Spring boot - 2.5.0), I put @EnableConfigServer annotation in the main class.

But swagger is not working, when I am removing this annotation in this case swagger is working properly but the property file is not coming from GitHub repo in the microservice

Comment: Same here! Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
spring.cloud.config.server.prefix= /cloud
```

this line in your application properties for configure the cloud config server path. And give permission that address like that

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/cloud/**")
                .and()
                .httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall());
    }
```

your cloud address will be like that

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:******/cloud
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).